# Laravel 5.1 route issue

Tags: laravel-5.1, laravel-routing

I have installed laravel framework (latest version 5.1), After installing successfully , I have a path issue on localhost while reaching the welcome blade page. Usually it can be reached by `localhost/laravel/public` but when I write this url it redirects to`localhost/public`and 404 not found page opens. While when I access the welcome page by `localhost/laravel/public/index.php` then the welcome page appears.. Normally the path is `localhost/laravel/public` but in my case it is `localhost/laravel/public/index.php`. How to reach the welcome page by`localhost/laravel/public`?

Comment: may be **rewrite_module** is not enable on apache.

Comment: rewrite_module is also enabled..I have check it.

Answer (score 0):

This is basically the Apache configuration, make sure to have the following:

1. Your document route is the public directory. So http://localhost can respond directly to the Welcome page.
2. Make sure the `.htaccess` files is available in your `/laravel/public` directory.
3. Ensure to have `mod-rewrite` enabled.

A sample Apache configuration below:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>                                                                                                                                                        
        # The ServerName directive sets the request scheme, hostname and port that                                                                                        
        # the server uses to identify itself. This is used when creating                                                                                                  
        # redirection URLs. In the context of virtual hosts, the ServerName                                                                                               
        # specifies what hostname must appear in the request's Host: header to                                                                                            
        # match this virtual host. For the default virtual host (this file) this                                                                                          
        # value is not decisive as it is used as a last resort host regardless.                                                                                           
        # However, you must set it for any further virtual host explicitly.                                                                                               
        #ServerName www.example.com                                                                                                                                       

        ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost                                                                                                                                   
        DocumentRoot /var/www/laravel/public                                                                                                                 

        # Available loglevels: trace8, ..., trace1, debug, info, notice, warn,                                                                                            
        # error, crit, alert, emerg.                                                                                                                                      
        # It is also possible to configure the loglevel for particular                                                                                                    
        # modules, e.g.                                                                                                                                                   
        #LogLevel info ssl:warn                                                                                                                                           

        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log                                                                                                                              
        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined                                                                                                                   

        # For most configuration files from conf-available/, which are                                                                                                    
        # enabled or disabled at a global level, it is possible to                                                                                                        
        # include a line for only one particular virtual host. For example the                                                                                            
        # following line enables the CGI configuration for this host only                                                                                                 
        # after it has been globally disabled with "a2disconf".                                                                                                           
        #Include conf-available/serve-cgi-bin.conf                                                                                                                        
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: Where can I find the above apache configuration?

Comment: That depends on your Apache installation, probably `/etc/apache2/sites-available/000-default.conf`

Comment: These points have been cleared as u say:                                              1-Make sure the .htaccess files is available in your /laravel/public directory.
2-Ensure to have mod-rewrite enabled.   but have the same issue

Comment: Do you have the correct Apache `.conf` file in place, then you reloaded your apache?

Comment: Actually I am not sure where to find Apache .conf file

Comment: well, i copy the public folder and rename it to publicc then goes to localhost/laravel/publicc then welcome page appears... but this not happens with the public directory